# How to do center videoView zoom?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a video player app. But when I am scaling for video zoom, So this app is not cropping in the center in some devices but this code working fine on other devices.
please help me. Or give me any suggestions. Thank you

**here is my code**

```
    final static float move = 200;
        float ratio = 1.0f;
        int hasDist;
        float baseRatio;
       int position = -1;
       VideoView videoView;
       Uri uri;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video__player_);

    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
        String path = videoList.get(position).getPath();

        uri = Uri.parse(path);

        videoView.setVideoPath(path);
}



 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getPointerCount()==2){

            int action = event.getAction();
            int mainAction = action&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

            if (mainAction ==MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
                hasDist=getDistion(event);
                baseRatio = ratio;
            }else {
                float scale = (getDistion(event)-hasDist)/move;
                float fatcher = (float)Math.pow(2,scale);
                ratio = Math.min(1024.0f,Math.max(0.0f,baseRatio*fatcher));
                videoView.setScaleX(ratio);
                videoView.setScaleY(ratio);
            }


        }
        return true;


    }

    private int getDistion(MotionEvent event) {
        int dx = (int) (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        int dy = (int) (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        return (int) (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: sorry, what you mean sir?

Comment: Remove "Thank you"... Everything is in the link.